# am not sure how to write on other file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, yaml

hi  i have this script called script.sh have 2 variable

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p " name " name
read -p " last " last 
( here am not sure what to do but if possible to open file name.yaml write $name $last save and exit)
cat name.yaml
```

and i have another file in name.yaml

```
 username: $name
  lastname: $last
```

executing script :

```
./script.sh
   name AAA
   last BBB
 username: AAA
  lastname: BBB
```

can i do something like this ? thanks for reading and thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable, you can `echo` that variable to the file:

```
echo "username: $name" > newfile
echo "lastname: $last" >> newfile
```

Read on "stream redirection in shell"

Comment: thank you for responding , this idea is good but what if i have more then 6 variable any solution to open file write on it and save it in the same running script ? thank you again

Answer (score 0):

To create a properly formatted YAML file from your variables, it is best to use a YAML-aware tool, such as `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

With it, you could write your script like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS= read -r -p 'Username : ' name1
IFS= read -r -p 'Last name: ' name2
IFS= read -r -p 'Quote    : ' quote

yq -y -n \
    --arg username "$name1" \
    --arg lastname "$name2" \
    --arg quote "$quote" \
    '$ARGS.named' >name.yaml
```

This uses `yq` to create a YAML document containing each of the keys and their corresponding values as given on the command line using the multiple instances of the `--arg` option.

Running this would interactively ask the user for three strings and would then create a YAML file with the three keys `username`, `lastname` and `quote`:

```bash
$ ./script
Username : myself
Last name: von Self
Quote    : "Just do it!"
```

```bash
$ cat name.yaml
username: myself
lastname: von Self
quote: '"Just do it!"'
```

Note that the last key's value is given an extra set of single quotes automatically to account for the fact that I entered double quotes that should be literal.